# Nav Bar or No Nav Bar

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, toggle

I am creating a mobile app that has a flat hierarchical structure.  Users will primarily navigate using a slide-out menu (nav drawer).  The screens at the top hierarchical level of the app have toogle switches with long names to toggle back and forth between the users and their friend's information.  I am considering eliminating the nav bar.  Should I have any concerns about Google or Apple approving the app?

With navigation bar:

[image]

Without navigation bar:

[image]

Comment: I will allow users to horizontal scroll some screens at the top level of the app and I am not certain if nav bar can scroll horizontally with the screens.

Comment: I've edited your image because the original version was very confusing to interpret. Please let me know if my interpretation of them was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the red bar will help keep it clearly separate from the content. I have had this problem when scrolling the hamburger gets lost and becomes a usability issue. Before you worry about apple and google you should ensure that the navigation works for your users. IMO the red bar or something to keep a hierarchy between the nav and your content is important.